# Spring Data Mongo Aggregation Function with both $trim and $toLower

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Trying to convert the following mongo query but cant find a solution to trim and toLower using Spring Aggregation queries

```
db.qabr.aggregate([
        { $match: {name: { "$ne": '' } }},
        { $group: {
                _id: { 'name': { input: { $trim: { input: { $toLower : '$name' }}}}, 'qabrNumber': '$qabrNumber', 'qabristaan': '$qabristaan' }, // can be grouped on multiple properties
                count: { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
        { $match: {
                count: { "$gt": 1 }    // Duplicates considered as count greater than one
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

If I do the following:

```
        AddFieldsOperation trimAndLowerName = Aggregation.addFields()
                .addFieldWithValue("name", StringOperators.Trim.valueOf(
                        StringOperators.ToLower.lowerValueOf("name")
                ))
                .build();
```

I keep getting 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$trim'' on server

However running just trim or just toLower works:

```
        AddFieldsOperation trimName = Aggregation.addFields()
                .addFieldWithValue("name", StringOperators.ToLower.lowerValueOf("name"))
                .build();
```

Comment: _"If I do the following:..."_ The code with both String operations works fine on Spring Boot 2.5.5 and MongoDB v 4.2.8.

Comment: Turns out we were using embedded mongo in the tests which was pulling a really old v3 version of mongo even with Spring upgraded, this caused confusion as the local mongo instance worked as expected manually running the query